# Ionic 2 file plugin : how to create file in ionic 3

Tags: file, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to create a file in my phone but I am always invoking only else part

**app.component.ts**

```
file.checkDir(file.dataDirectory, 'silapathigaram')
      .then(_ => {
        console.log('Directory exists');

      })
      .catch(err => { 
        console.log('Directory doesnt exist');
        file.createDir('cordova.file.applicationDirectory', 'silapathigaram', false)
        .then(
          (files) => {
            // do something
            console.log("success");
          }
        ).catch(
          (err) => {
            // do something
            console.log("error"); // i am invoking only this part
          }
        );
       });
```

> what am I doing wrong? I am checking file name '**silapathigaram**' and if it does not exist I am trying to create one
>
> but I am invoking only error part my code

Comment: what error does it print?

Comment: i am not getting any error my console prints only error part of this `.createDir` @suraj

Answer (score 1):

while creating the directory use code

```
file.createDir(file.externalRootDirectory, 'silapathigaram', true).then((val) => {
      console.log("Created");
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log("error is ",e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error. you need to send value of [`file.applicationDirectory`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#applicationDirectory) not the *string literal* `'cordova.file.applicationDirectory'`

Change  the call to:

```
file.createDir(file.applicationDirectory, 'silapathigaram', false)
```

Make sure to remove the single quotes as well.

Comment: log the err object..`err=>console.log(err)`

Comment: `function FileError(error)
ABORT_ERR
:
3
ENCODING_ERR
:
5
INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR
:
9
INVALID_STATE_ERR
:
7
NOT_FOUND_ERR
:
1
NOT_READABLE_ERR
:
4
NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR
:
6
PATH_EXISTS_ERR
:
12
QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR
:
10
SECURITY_ERR
:
2
SYNTAX_ERR
:
8
TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR
:
11`

Comment: now i solved and i getting success of the `file.createDir` but when i check in my phone storage i am not able to see my folder

Comment: yes i changed to `dataDirectory` and created a file silapathigaram but i am not able to find one in my phone memory

Comment: I think i have to give correct path for creating the directory

Comment: yes.. did you mean to create here file.dataDirectory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141894/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).